# Dropdown not populating using ajax and controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I asked a question earlier that was along the same lines. The issue in the previous question was that I was trying to call the controller action using an html helper, but it was in an external .js file.

I now moved the .ajax call to a script tag in the view, but the dropdown is still not populating. When I check out the network tab in the browser, I am getting a 500 Error back on the request.

Ajax call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetBranch", "Report")',
        type: "GET",
        success: $.each(function(result) {
            $("#dropdown2").append('<option value=' + result.BranchId + '>' + result.BranchName + '</option>');
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult GetBranch()
    {
        using (var entities = new TestEntities())
        {
            var branches = entities.Branches;

            return Json(branches.Select(t => new { Text = t.BranchName, Value = t.BranchId }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Additionally, I am not sure I am using `$.each` correctly. There are about 100 branches. I cannot use a `@DropDownListFor` because I must use a `<select>` that already exists. Am I using the `JsonResult` correctly?

Comment: This is a pretty good example you have setup here. In the future if you have this much information and are stuck on something a little trivial you should bring your asp.net mvc questions which may be too small for Stack Overflow to the c# chat room here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7/c

Comment: I had no idea there were chatrooms. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

Few things going on here. Overall you were close to getting this correct. `.Select` is going to return an `IEnumerable` once it is done with its projection. As a result of that, the set of projected objects has not been enumerated and are still dynamic proxies attached to the data context.

When the call for serialization is made, it attempts to serialize an object which has not been enumerated and that is where your server error is occurring. Make sure to call `.ToList()` there to enumerate the enumerable.

```
return Json(branches.Select(t => new { 
    Text = t.BranchName, 
    Value = t.BranchName //should this be t.BranchId ?
}).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
///^^^^^^^^
```

Also, back in the client side, the jQuery is incorrect as you suspected. Each needs to be called inside of the success function callback, passing in the result of the success into each and using `this` to reference each individual returned record.

As a result of your Select statement projecting the BranchName into Text and BranchName into Value (... wait, should that be BranchId into Value?) make sure you also reference those inside of your jquery callback.

```
success: function(result) {
 //if there are so many results, it may be best to cache your selector
 var dropdown2 = $("#dropdown2");
 $.each(result, function(){ 
  dropdown2.append('<option value=' + this.Value + '>' + this.Text + '</option>');
 });
}
```

Comment: No real need to `.ToList()` and I think you mean `'<option value=' + this.Value + '>' + this.Text + '</option>'`

Comment: I did mean value= .value thanks. With serialization though, you cannot serialize an enumerable. The set must be enumerated in order to execute the sql query underneath in EF.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `function` not `$.each` to `success` and `$.each` is also wrong, find the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetBranch", "Report")',
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, result) {
        $("#dropdown2").append('<option value=' + result.BranchId + '>' + result.BranchName + '</option>');
    })
    }

});
```

Check some [jQuery ajax examples](http://www.sitepoint.com/demos/ajax/)

Comment: Still getting a 500 Internal Server Error. Figured my controller action code was somehow causing the error

Comment: 500 error something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is. once check with your web server.